# Python Django working with multiple database simultaneously

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've been trying to add in a functionality to my already existing Django application. 
Currently, my application only services multiple users belonging to an organization. 
I'm trying to accomplish a task wherein:

1. Multiple organizations can work with my application by having separate databases. This way organization-specific data is private to individual organizations.
2. For every organization that wants to subscribe to the web app services, the web app shall use a database template to create the database for the new organization and commission it.
3. The web app should handle/service all organizations simultaneously.

Is this possible?

Comment: Seems you are looking for multi tenancy django apps. follow this [link for more](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/)

Comment: You can create a middleware to change between different database configurations based on Subdomain. The other way could be simply run the same app instance on different ports with a different ENV Variable for each client.